# Getting StopIteration error in generator function

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I'm using a generator function to returns 10 '*valid*' numbers one after the other.

The `check_id_valid()` function returns `True` or `False` depending on whether the number is valid or not. The problem is that I'm getting a `StopIteration` error after producing only one *valid* number.

The `check_id_valid()` function is working well, I checked it by sending it parameters directly: `print(check_id_valid(123456780))`.

The generator function:

```
def id_generator(Id_number):
    Id_number +=1
    valid_id = (check_id_valid(Id_number))
    while not valid_id:
        Id_number += 1
        valid_id = check_id_valid(Id_number)
        yield Id_number

def main():
    id_gen = id_generator(123456780)
    try:
        for item in range(10):
            print(next(id_gen))
    except (illigalDigits, illigalException) as e:
        print(e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The error:

```
   print(next(id_gen))
StopIteration
>>>
```

Comment: `StopIteration` is built-in behavior that an iterator uses to tell whatever's iterating over it that there are no more values. But in your case, it looks like your function will only ever `yield` a single value - are you sure that you don't mean to `return` instead?

Comment: Yes I'm sure and with `return` I get an error - `TypeError: 'int' object is not an iterator
`. The generator function must have a `yield` command

Comment: Your indentation was off... I've tried to fix it so that people can just copy/paste... but actually I might have gone too far? Where is actually your second `yield`? That said, I could not really reproduce your behavior... you should `yield` for each crack of the iteration... and return when done... which happens here with implicit `return None`

Comment: If you expect `id_generator` to be an infinite iterator, you need something more like this: `def id_generator(i): while True: i += 1; if check_id_valid(i): yield i`.

Comment: Why does the `id_generator` skip the first two IDs? And did you test `check_id_valid` only on `123456780` or also on the next few numbers after that?

Comment: @tobias_k it suppose to retrun the next valid ID number, and I checked it on the next few numbers after

Comment: Thanks @ekhumoro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your generator function only `yield`s once, so needs to be changed to do so more than that. Here's a runnable example and the output it produces:

```
# A little scaffolding to make code runnable.
class illigalDigits(Exception): pass
class illigalException(Exception): pass

def check_id_valid(id):
    return id  # Consider anything valid.
########

def id_generator(Id_number):
    while True:
        Id_number += 1
        valid_id = check_id_valid(Id_number)
        if valid_id:
            yield Id_number

def main():
    id_gen = id_generator(123456780)
    try:
        for _ in range(10):
            print(next(id_gen))
    except (illigalDigits, illigalException) as e:
        print(e)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
123456781
123456782
123456783
123456784
123456785
123456786
123456787
123456788
123456789
123456790
```

Comment: Thank you @martineau, now I understand what was the issue and your soltion solve the problem.

Comment: Or `return filter(check_id_valid, itertools.count(Id_number+1))`

Comment: @tobias_k: Or the equivalent `return (id for id in itertools.count(Id_number+1) if check_id_valid(id))`.